# How to get the values of uri in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a code which is shown below which contains uri and suppose the uri passed is http://website.com/accounts/school/index/fr_id/1/stateID/14683/school_name/BANGALORE INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL(UOL)/

```
      $uri=$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4); 

     if(isset($uri['fr_id'])) {  $fr_id=$uri['fr_id'];  }
     else{  $fr_id='';  }
     if(isset($uri['stateID'])) { $stateID=$uri['stateID']; }
     else{  $stateID='';  }
     if(isset($uri['school_name'])) {  $school_name=$uri['school_name'];  }
     else{  $school_name='';  

     echo $fr_id.$stateID.$school_name;exit;
     }
```

Using this statement , $uri=$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4);  I cant get the values which is passed in the url and need to be checked with the if statement. Can anyone help me out with this ? When I am echoing the values of $fr_id, $stateID and $school_name, they are empty.

Comment: You should try `$this->uri->segment(3)`  to get URL part. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function function_name()
 {
     $uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(); 
     echo $pp=$uri['stateID'];
     echo $school_name=$uri['school_name'];
     echo $fr_id=$uri['fr_id'];
 }
```

It will working fine

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

do it like this :

```
$uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);
/* OR simply use this */
$uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();  

$fr_id = ! empty($uri['fr_id']) ? $uri['fr_id'] : '';

$stateID = ! empty($uri['stateID']) ? $uri['stateID'] : '';
$school_name = ! empty($uri['school_name']) ? $uri['school_name'] : '';

echo $fr_id.' '.$stateID.' '.$school_name;die;
/*Output - 1 14683 BANGALORE*/
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::uri_to_assoc